# My chat account reputation is incorrect after merging my account

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, merge-accounts

I have merged my another account with this about a week ago. But, after merging that account my reputation in Stack Overflow Chat is not getting changed whenever I get an up- or down vote. It has been stuck at 955. I don't know what is happening; I can't make room as gallery even I have 2500 points on my merged account.

- Stack Overflow [User Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761928/shell)
- Chat [User Profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3761928/shell)

My account was merged with another, so why my is my reputation on Chat are still showing the old amount?
Will my Stack Overflow Chat reputation never get updated?

**EDITED:**

I have also checked my account in https://chat.stackexchange.com site. I am shocked about that i can do chat with my deleted Account.

- Stack Exchange Chat [User Profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/115198/nimesh)

I was just trying to access my Stack Exchange Chat site account using **Shell** user but, it has logged in with my old user **Nimesh** which has been merged with **Shell**. And it is also showing incorrect reputation.

**REMARK:** The problem defined above was having until **Marc Gravell♦** has not corrected it.

Comment: ohh sorry.. i missed *not* @Sumurai8

Comment: No problem. That just confused me a bit ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that was confusing @Sumurai8 thanks for correcting me..

Comment: Same happened with my first account merge.

Comment: @bjb568 then how did you get back your reps in SO Chat?

Comment: @Shell Anna Lear fixed it manually for me.

Comment: So, that means still there is an issue in merging two accounts. Should I add the bug tag in my question? @bjb568

Comment: Yup, it's a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chat isn't entirely integrated into the account merge process; I'll add a card to our list to see about improving this. The reason your new rep wasn't showing is that it wasn't able to complete your regular profile update due to a conflict in the account-id vs your old record.

I have merged the two accounts in chat (that functionality exists), and clicked the button to refresh your profile from stackoverflow; you should be sorted now.

Comment: But, What about Stack Exchange account.Still, I can access my old account in Chat.StackExchange site even it has been deleted from StackExchange site.

Comment: @Shell your chat.SE was already pointing to the right account, but was confused about your user; fixed

Comment: Hi Marc. Would you mind fixing my chat account as well? What do you need? This http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4136325 and http://stackoverflow.com/users/480982/thomas-weller ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have same problem , could you solve my merged accounts problem too?