# User's SO chat profile failed to update

Tags: bug, chat, users

I [discovered today in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35452890#35452890) a user who's [StackOverflow chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6532328/john-doe-2) failed to update to the new name changed months ago (according to the user) because the [link to their SO profile obtained from the chat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6532328/john-doe-2) says the page is not found.

Their [StackExchange chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/229183/utdev) has updated, as has [their entire StackExchange account](https://stackexchange.com/users/5971953/utdev?tab=accounts), but the SO chat profile still has an old name, reputation, and (somehow) a different user ID.

There's got to be a bug here. Any idea what the cause is?

Comment: [Duplicate meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159938/215485) (found after the cause was found in [Undo's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342845/2065702) below)

Answer (score 3):

That user was merged into the other user you're seeing, which would cause the things you're observing.

There isn't a way for me to merge chat accounts. If the user wants continuity, they should log in to [their other chat account](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5106620/utdev?tab=general).

Comment: Thanks for the information! It's interesting that the system allows this other account to still be logged in after the merge. I would think it would not allow it. Any idea why it does allow it?

Comment: According to [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268482/2065702) there is a way to merge chat accounts...

Comment: @ZachSaucier Pretty sure it doesn't exist for moderators. May be a developer thing.